# remove surrounding quotes from fields while loading data into hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to load a table with input data into hive. I have data in the following format.

```
"153662";"0002241447";"0"
"153662";"000647036X";"0"
"153662";"0020434901";"0"
"153662";"0020973403";"0"
"153662";"0028604202";"0"
"153662";"0030437512";"0"
```

I want to load this data into a table with two varchar columns and one int column.But the surrounding double quotes trouble me. I have created the following table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Table(A varchar(50),B varchar(50),C varchar(50))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

but the quotes around the field also become part of field as shown below.

```
"276725"    "034545104X"    "0"
"276726"    "0155061224"    "5"
```

I want to ignore them. Also I want the third field to be read as INT. Currently it becomes NULL when I provide third field as INT while making table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use [Csv-Serde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde) for this.

```
CREATE TABLE Table(A varchar(50),B varchar(50),C varchar(50))
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(
    "separatorChar" = ";",
    "quoteChar"     = "\""
)  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: I do not want to use SERDE as I do not fully understand it. Is there any native hive feature for the same ? also I ma geting problems in using it. I get the error below : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot
 validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde

Comment: You will have to use the serde jar that is  compatible with the distribution.

Comment: Note that this SerDe is not supported by Impala.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to achieve this:

1. Use CSV serde
2. Use regex serde- regex `"\"(.*)\"\;\"(.*)\"\;\"(.*)\""`
3. Load data to external table then remove double quotes:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE source(
>   a string,
>   b String,
>   c String)
>   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' LOCATION 'xyz';
>
> CREATE TABLE destination AS SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(a,'"',''), REGEXP_REPLACE(b,'"',''), CAST ( REGEXP_REPLACE(c,'"','') AS BIGINT) FROM source;

Answer (score 0):

> > Hive query to remove double quotes around the string.

Example:
col2 value: "my name is, abc"

`select col1, (regexp_replace(col2,'"','')) as col2 from table;`

Output: my name is, abc