# How to read quoted CSV with NULL values into Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm trying to create an external table in Athena using quoted CSV file stored on S3. The problem is, that my CSV contain missing values in columns that should be read as INTs. Simple example:

CSV:

```
id,height,age,name
1,,26,"Adam"
2,178,28,"Robert"
```

CREATE TABLE DEFINITION:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema.test_null_unquoted (
  id INT,
  height INT,
  age INT,
  name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT 
SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'separatorChar' = ",",
'quoteChar' = '"',
'skip.header.line.count' = '1'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/test_null/unquoted/'
```

`CREATE TABLE` statement runs fine but as soon as I try to query the table, I'm getting `HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value ''`.

I tried making the CSV look like this (quote empty string):

```
"id","height","age","name"
1,"",26,"Adam"
2,178,28,"Robert"
```

But it's not working.

Tried specifying `'serialization.null.format' = ''` in `SERDEPROPERTIES` - not working.

Tried specifying the same via `TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format'='')` - still nothing.

It works, when you specify all columns as `STRING` but that's not what I need.

Therefore, the question is, is there **any way** to read a quoted CSV (quoting is important as my real data is much more complex) to Athena with correct column specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty way to handle these data:

CSV:

```
id,height,age,name
1,,26,"Adam"
2,178,28,"Robert"
3,123,34,"Bill, Comma"
4,183,38,"Alex"
```

DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stackoverflow.test_null_unquoted (
  id INT,
  height INT,
  age INT,
  name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- Or use Windows Line Endings
LOCATION 's3://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
;
```

The issue is that it is not handling the quote characters in the last field.  Based on the documentation provided by [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html), this makes sense as the LazySimpleSerDe given the following from [Hive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8763).

I suspect the solution is using the following SerDe `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe`.

I will work on the regex later.

**Edit:**

Regex as promised:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stackoverflow.test_null_unquoted (
  id INT,
  height INT,
  age INT,
  name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "(.*),(.*),(.*),\"(.*)\""
)
LOCATION 's3://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1') -- Does not appear to work
;
```

[image]

Note: `RegexSerDe` did not seem to work properly with `TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')`.  That could be due to the [Hive version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/hive-external-table-skip-first-row) used by Athena or the SerDe.  In your case, you can likely just exclude rows where `ID IS NULL`.

**Further Reading:**

[Stackoverflow - remove surrounding quotes from fields while loading data into hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617824/remove-surrounding-quotes-from-fields-while-loading-data-into-hive)

[Athena - OpenCSVSerDe for Processing CSV](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html)

Comment: Does anyone know what version of Hive is being used by Athena?

Comment: Indeed the RegexSerDe works as expected, thanks! I'm only wondering, since Athena is just an abstraction layer on top of the existing data and I imagine the file is parsed each time it is read, are there any performance differences between using RegexSerDe and OpenCSVSerDe?

Comment: That is a really interesting question.  I've been meaning to setup some Athena benchmarking tests and to be honest, I've never considered the differences between different Serializer/Deserializers.

Comment: I have not ran any serious benchmarks but from what I've tested the performance of the regex serde is extremely poor comparing to OpenCSV. I have  a table that has 5kk rows and 20 columns of various types. If I run a simple count(*) on the table created with regex the query runs for over 20 minutes. For the CSV it's a matter of seconds. But who knows, I might be doing something else wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Would this regex method work for any number of columns? How do you interpret regex pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to get both support for quoted fields *and* support for null values in Athena. You have to choose either or.

You can use OpenCSVSerDe and type all columns as string, that will give you support for quoted fields, and emtpty strings for empty fields. Cast values at query time using `TRY_CAST` or `CASE/WHEN`.

Or you can use `LazySimpleSerDe` and strip quotes at query time.

I would go for OpenCSVSerDe because you can always create a view with all the type conversion and use the view for your regular queries.

You can read all the nitty-gritty details of working with CSV in Athena here: [The Athena Guide: Working with CSV](https://athena.guide/articles/working-with-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Use OpenCSVSerDe and convert all columns into string. Read more: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-hive-bad-data-error-csv/