# Get particular values from a string in hive

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with two columns both are strings

```
name            details
"john" , {"addr":"NY","phone":"1234"}
"john" , {"addr":"CA", "phone":"7145"}
"mary" , {"addr":"BOS","phone":"1234"}
```

Is there a way to convert the string column to sort of JSON to access values by key. 
Example if I run query

```
SELECT name, details['addr'] , details['phone'] FROM table_a;
```

I should get
john, NY, 1234
john, CA, 7145
mary, BOS, 1234

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_json_object`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) and then access the `addr` and `phone` from string.

```
hive>  with cte as (
        select string('"john"')col1,
               string('{"addr":"NY","phone":"1234"}')col2)
        select regexp_replace(col1,"\"","")col1,get_json_object(col2,'$.addr')col2 
        from cte;
```

**`Result:`**

```
col1    col2
john    NY
```

To escape quotes we can also use csv serde with quote character as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617824/remove-surrounding-quotes-from-fields-while-loading-data-into-hive).

Answer (score 0):

One more method using `str_to_map`:

```
select name, details_map['addr'] as addr , details_map['phone'] as phone
from 
(
select name, str_to_map(regexp_replace(details,'\\{|\\}| ?\\"','')) as details_map
from your_table
)s;
```