# Trying to convert the string to array<string> type in hive using collect_set

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, impala

I have two columns in my table (date,users) which are strings.

```
date               users
2019-01-01        '"U10000","U20000"'
```

I am trying to convert the `users` column to `array<string>`, and getting `\` in values. I didn't find any spaces in string values, so why am I getting '\' in  new array column?

this is my query and the result it produces:

```
Select date,collect_set(users)  as user_arr from mytable group by date

date                user_arr
2019-01-01      ["\"U10000\",\"U20000\""]
```

Comment: Checkout here  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844602/4959282

Comment: Thanks @Kishan,I tried this, still not getting expected output

Comment: i tried this ....... Select to_date(current_date()),collect_set("\"Hello\"") group by to_date(current_date())

Comment: Hope this can help   Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38618050/4959282